# The derivative of $\max (0,x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

there is a very fundamental question that makes me really confused... Does the derivative of function
$$
f(x)=[x]^+
$$
exist? Specifically, $[x]^+=\max[0,x]$.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give further information on how you define $[x]^+$?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information! I have modified the question...

Comment: At $x=0$ the derivative does not exist. What does exist there is the left and the rigth derivative but they are different. Can you tell me what they are ?

Comment: @Kurt G Is it that $f'(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f'(x)=1$ for $x>0$?

Comment: Yes. These ordinary derivatives exist for $x\not=0$. But what are the left and right derivatives of $f$ at $x=0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is just the piecewise linear function:

- $f(x) = 0$ (and $f'(x) = 0$) if $x \le 0$
- $f(x) = x$ (and $f'(x) = 1$) if $x \ge 0$

So the derivative exists except at $x = 0$, where it's undefined because the left and right derivatives are different.  Unless you use the [“symmetric”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) (aka  “centered”) derivative definition $f'_s(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}$, in which case $f'_s(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Best not to use the same notation $f′(0)$ for a generalized derivative. Also, for over a century we have called this the *symmetric derivative* with a notation like $f_s'(x) $or perhaps $SD\,f(x)$. Has that language disappeared in recent texts?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: I learned it as “centered difference”, but that was in the context of *numerical approximation* of derivatives (as my background is in computer programming and *computational* mathematics), whereas “symmetric derivative” is more of a “pure” mathematical concept.  But I've added the *s* subscript so you can turn off your pedantry alarm.

Comment: Pedantry alarm hard wired in "on" position.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ you described is basically
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if $x\le 0$}\\
x &\text{ if $x>0$}
\end{cases}$$
This function is clearly differentiable everywhere except at $x=0$.